# Script for Google Sheets to calculate time by clicking?

Tags: google-apps-script

First, I'm trying to make a button to change the cell value; the cell's format is set to Hour:Minute.

I need a button to add 30 minutes to the cell value.
So I tried like a dumb:

```
function timePlus() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var timeCount = ss.getRange("G10"); 
  var timeAdd = timeCount.getValue();
  timeCount.setValue(timeAdd+30); 
}
```

If I click the button the cell's value turns into like this:

Fri Dec 29 1899 19:32:08 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)30

I admit, I never learned about script code thingy.

Second, I also want to set the clock(the time formatted cell) starts from 09:00 and ends 21:00 then skip to 09:00 again. Like if I click the plus button enough times to change the clock to 21:00, one more click changes the clock to 09:00 again. I'm so clueless so couldn't try anything about this one.

Third, after the clock reset to 09:00, +1 to another cell like a number-of-days counter. I've tried:

```
function checkTime() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var timeCount = ss.getRange("G10:H10"); 
  var dateCount = ss.getRange("I2:I3"); 
  var dateAdd = dateCount.getValue(); 
  if(timeCount.getValue() == "9:00:00 AM"); 
  dateAdd.setValue(dateAdd+1); 
}
```

but nothing happened.

Anyone think those are possible?

Comment: ````timeAdd+30```` would not add 30 minutes, it would just concatenate 30 to the time in G10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

You would need to make use of the [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) object to manipulate date/time in Apps Script:

As an example, your code to increment time by 30 minutes, reset to 9 AM from 9 PM, and increment a counter would look like this:

```
function timePlus() { 
  const HALF_HOUR = 1000*60*30;
  const HALF_DAY = 1000*60*60*12;
  const NINE_PM = -2209068000000;

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  var timeCount = ss.getRange("G10");
  var dateCount = ss.getRange("I2");
  
  var timeAdd = timeCount.getValue();
  var dateAdd = dateCount.getValue();
  var old = new Date(timeAdd).valueOf();
  console.log(Session.getScriptTimeZone());

  if (old == NINE_PM) {
    timeCount.setValue(Utilities.formatString(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(old - HALF_DAY), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "HH:mm:ss")));
    dateCount.setValue(dateAdd + 1);
  }
  else {
    timeCount.setValue(Utilities.formatString(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(old + HALF_HOUR), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "HH:mm:ss")));
  }
  
}
```

**IMPORTANT:**

Please make sure that the spreadsheet time zone is the same as the script time zone. You can check the script time zone by using `console.log(Session.getScriptTimeZone());` and running the function manually. The time zone will be visible in the Execution Log. Then change the sheet time zone in `File -> Spreadsheet Settings`.

P.S. If you are overwhelmed with the milliseconds computation, you can read the reference below:

[Dates in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)

[Session.getScriptTimeZone()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getscripttimezone)

Comment: Really appreciate your answer! But the button changes the time 9:00:00 AM to 8:02:00 PM, means the code increment time by 11 hours and 2 minutes. I edited the part "HH:mm:ss" to "HH:mm" so it looks llike 00:00 format but still don't see what's the problem. Is this about milliseconds problem?

Comment: Please make sure that the spreadsheet time zone is the same as the script time zone. You can check the script time zone by using console.log(Session.getScriptTimeZone()); and running the function manually. Then change the sheet time zone in File -> Spreadsheet Settings. I edited my answer to include this.

Comment: God now it works! The code increases exactly 30 minutes but the time doesn't reset to 9:00 AM and counting date doesn't works too. Would you mind to check the sheet please? I got the test sheet that you can edit. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WG-dRZb25JNiw6-x5sCXBbDIkeCFoMii2A4auRXqLY8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Ah, the time zone changed the value of 9PM in the sheet to -2209068000000. I edited the answer again. To check the value you can add console.log(old) to the code and copy the value.

Comment: JESUS The code works PERFECTLY!!! You have my many many many many thanks, you earned it! This is one of the nicest things in my life, you made my day! Thank you!

Comment: Much appreciated :)